# Complete class and method/function library for swift 3

Tags: swift3

I'm new to iOS development. I'm enrolled for some courses where they teach by example. The course introduces you to a few classes and its functions / methods in each session.

Is there a complete repository / reference for all swift 3 in-built classes and functions along with what they do?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode, select "Help" and then "Documentation and API Reference."